# shl won't move bits between 2 byte groups (x86)

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, emu8086

I have this code for calculating a factorial:

```
jmp start

; variables
num1 DD 0001h

start:  mov cl, al

        factorial_loop: ; cx = ax -> 1
            mov al, cl
            mul num1
            ; combine dx and ax into num1
            mov num1, dx
            shl num1, 16
            add num1, ax
        loop factorial_loop

mov ah, 0
int 16h

ret
```

At the start of the code I declared num1 as a 4 byte variable.
Let's assume num1 is divided in 2 byte groups: num1(left) and num1(right).
When I shift the bits they don't move from num1(right) to num1(left).
How can I solve this?

Comment: What assembler is this?

Comment: I use emu8086 (x86)

Comment: Even if that did work, that's not how you accumulate a 32-bit product.  8086 doesn't have a 32x32 => 32 multiply, only 16x16 => 32.  And you're only setting the low 8 bits of AX before using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working in 16-bit assembler, so you cannot shift a 32-bit value with a 16-bit instruction.

```
shl num1, 16
```

is implicitly the same as (not sure if your assembler supports this syntax, but you should be able to get the idea):

```
shl word ptr ds:[num1], 16
```

in 8086/80286 assembler.  There is no 32-bit equivalent in 8086/80286 assembler.

Since you appear to be working with 16-bit code, you could solve this in one of two ways:

1) declare two 16-bit words rather than one 32-bit word, such as

```
numlo dw 0     ; these are encoded exactly like num1,
numhi dw 0     ; but are declared separately for easier use

...

mov numlo,dx   ; just write to the appropriate 16-bit word
mov numhi,ax   ; without the need to shift at all
```

2) or apply a manual offset, such as

```
mov [num1+2],dx
mov num1,ax
```

You will have to determine the correct syntax for your assembler for the manual offset, although the above example should be very close, based on your code.

Comment: In real 8086, the only shift instructions are shift by 1 and shift by CL.  So for shift counts other than 1, you need to put the count in CL.  (see this appendix from an old version of the NASM manual for details on which insn was introduced when: http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html).  (And other useful links in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Comment: @PeterCordes You are absolutely right, but in real 8086, mul doesn't support memory operands either, so this emulator is clearly more flexible on its instruction set than a real 8086, and I didn't think it important to mention either limitation if the instructions assemble.

Comment: Do you have a source for that claim?  [MUL](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MUL.html) uses the `/r` field as extra opcode bits, leaving the mode and `/m` bits available as usual to encode register or memory operands, just like for `add r/m16, imm16` and most other instructions with only one explicit operand.  (386 `imul r16, r/m16, imm16` being one of the few exceptions before BMI/BMI2 integer instructions that use a VEX encoding).  I don't remember ever hearing about some instructions not supporting all the usual encodings of the ModRM byte in 8086.